# How to convert to Korean initials

Tags: java, android, cjk

Hi Im working on a Korean android app.

Here I implemented a listview with alphabetic section headers to display contacts. I used substring method of String class to get the first letter as section header. For korean contacts also im taking first letter using substring method. Here I need to display Korean initials as ㄱ ㄴ ㄷ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅅ ㅇ ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ with respects to first letter of the Korean contact. I'm not really know which first letter of the Korean contact list matches with these Korean initials.

So please help me how i can do this or give me reference to follow...

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Useful writeup: http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/var/korean_hangul_unicode.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is normal behaviour in a Korean app to have intellisense from just an intial character - it seems to usually be done with a full Jamo. However, I see no reason why you shouldn't do it - so lets do it.

Firstly, you missed the double initials. These are different from the singles, as they do require a different key press (usually shift+character). Anyhow, your list of initials should be:

```
ㄱㄲㄴㄷㄸㄹㅁㅂㅃㅅㅆㅇㅈㅉㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎ
```

The first thing you need to do when an initial is typed in is to get the range of characters that start with that particular initial.

By looking at the Windows Character Map, I one can see that the first letter, Ka (가) is at Unicode point `0xAC00` (or decimal, `44032`), so to get any range, this value will have to be added to any calculation we do. So you should have a constant called `FirstLetter` or whatever, and its value should be `44032`.

까 is at `0xAE4C` (or decimal `44620`), so we now have a multiplier (i.e. the number of characters beginning with any particular initial - which is the same for all initials, so that is `44620-44032` which is `588`.

We now have enough information to implement your intellisense. If you have the initialisms in an array, we can use the index of the typed character in that array to find the range of characters that start with it.

So if we start with ㄱ, we obviously want to return everything from 가 to 깋. All 588 of them. So ㄱ gives us a '0', so we have

```
startCodePoint = index * 588 + 44032
// = 0 * 588 + 44032 == 44032 == 가
endCodePoint = (index + 1) * 588 + 44032
// this will include 까
```

And then you can just check that a particular character starts with 'ㄱ' by checking

```
if(charcode >= startCodePoint && charcode < endCodePoint) { ... }
```

where `charcode` is the first character of one of the items in your intellisense list.

Use a similar methodology to find out how to check that a character starts with say '가'. Everything is in order in Unicode, so this is a very simple task.

---

To get the initial letter of any character, you can use the above formula in reverse.

i.e.

1. Get the unicode value of the first character (e.g. 각)
2. Subtract 44032 from this value.
3. Divide this value by 588.
4. Use that value as the index to retrieve the intial character from the list of initials.

e.g.

```
String initials = "ㄱㄲㄴㄷㄸㄹㅁㅂㅃㅅㅆㅇㅈㅉㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎ";
int value = character.codePointAt(0);
value = (value - 44032) / 588;
String initial = initials.substring(value, 1);
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, Thank you somuch for your quick response. FYI Im not aware korean language. The above explained method is completely new to me. Im not really understand you saying as "Firstly, you missed the double initials." and you saying "The first thing you need to do when an initial is typed in is to get the range of characters that start with that particular initial." and " Windows Character Map" and  the "unicode point". FYI, Im not typing any thing here. Im getting phone contacts names and the taking first letter as section header for listview. This answer seems to work for me but

Comment: i don't understand how to use it.... can you please give me some more explanation or give me some reference to follow...

Comment: I see the same kind of explanation here in this link also http://dotnetpower.tistory.com/20 ... Im not sure hw i can do in Java same.

Comment: OK, basically you need to use my list of initials instead of your list of initials.

Comment: I will update my answer with how to get the initial of any particular character.

Comment: If there are things in Java that you don't understand, please try and break them down into different questions, or put some effort into working it out yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur help Vincent, you saved me. That's what i needed and it worked like a charm. This line String initial = initials.substring(value, 1); given me indexoutofbound exception. here i used char initial = initials.charAt(value); and converted to string as i need string as return value......

Comment: Hi vincent, Im unable to convert the 김 first letter to korean initial. Im getting value as -53 for int value = Character.codePointAt(koreanString,0);
     value = (value - 44032) / 588;. Im not sure about how to solve this issue.. Please let me know how to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: @VincentMcNabb McNabb, do you any search sample code for korean language in android or java?

Answer (score 0):

The international way is to fetch the Unicode int code. This in general might be more than one 16 bit char.

```
int codePoint = strng.codePointAt(0);
int indexToRest = Character.charCount(codePoint); // For your information
```

Comment: For Korean this will get a whole syllabic block, which is a precomposed character made up of up to five letters called jamo. The OP was specifically asking about getting only the first letter / jamo. This is equivalent to converting to [Unicode normalization form D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms) and *then* taking the first character.