# Get last character of korean word in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to get the last character of a Korean word (a `String`) but it's not working as planned. If I have the string: `"사람"`, I want to get the `"ㅁ"` but I am getting the `"람"`.

What I already have tried:

```
word.charAt(word.length-1); // gets 람
```

I have also checked if `"사람"` ends with `"ㅁ"` using `word.endsWith("ㅁ")`, but it returned false.

It gives true back if I ask, `word.endsWith("람")`.

Comment: `word.charAt(word.length()-1) == '람'` is consistent with `word.endsWith("람") == true`. Can you explain why you expect a different result?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472294/how-to-convert-to-korean-initials) It explains a lot about encoding and decoding korean strings

Comment: AFAICT, Korean is nowadays usually written in rows, left-to-right (like English), so `"사람"` does end with `"람"`. Are you expecting right-to-left interpretation (like Arabic)?

Comment: In unicode, `람` is considered a single character.

Comment: @Bill You are right I expected the same result, but I wanted to double check because I could't think of anything else.

Comment: @Bohemian I was expecting that "사람" would consist of 5 characters and that I would get the last character "ㅁ" back.

Comment: @TamasHegedus thanks that's what I was looking for. I don't think I can get the last character. Guess I will have to find a different way to do what I intended.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (for people who don't know Korean), what does the last glyph of that word mean and why / how does it break down into two different "characters"?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I was trying to make a Korean translator with several grammar points. In Korean allot of grammar points have to do with how a word ends(does it end with a consonant or a vowel). The word 사람" consists of " ㅅ ㅏ ㄹ ㅏ ㅁ" which means "Person" or "Human" . So I was hoping the get the last letter of the word, which is the "ㅁ" this is the M in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer uses information from [How to convert to Korean initials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472294/how-to-convert-to-korean-initials) and [The Korean Writing System](http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/var/korean_hangul_unicode.html). As the latter one describes, the Hangul is divided into (possible) three parts: initial, vowel, and tail consonant (if present). The tail consonant may consist of 2 consonants like `ㅆ`.
The unicode coding was, IMHO, quite brilliantly designed so that the Hangul character coding can be encoded/decoded using a formula, as described by (The Korean Writing System) as:

```
tail = mod ($hangulCodepoint − 44032, 28) 
vowel = 1 + mod ($hangulCodepoint − 44032 − tail, 588) / 28 
lead = 1 + int [ ($hangulCodepoint − 44032) / 588 ]
```

Since I need the same thing as you describe, I implemented the following:

```
private final static String getCharacter(final String character) {
    // the following characters are in the correct (i.e. Unicode) order
    final String initials = "ㄱㄲㄴㄷㄸㄹㅁㅂㅃㅅㅆㅇㅈㅉㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎ";// list of initials
    final String vowels = "ᅡᅢᅣᅤᅥᅦᅧᅨᅩᅪᅫᅬᅭᅮᅯᅰᅱᅲᅳᅴᅵ";// list of vowels
    final String finals = "ᆨᆩᆪᆫᆬᆭᆮᆯᆰᆱᆲᆳᆴᆵᆶᆷᆸᆹᆺᆻᆼᆽᆾᆿᇀᇁᇂ";// list of tail characters
    final int characterValue = character.codePointAt(0); // Unicode value
    final int hangulUnicodeStartValue = 44032;
    if (characterValue < hangulUnicodeStartValue)
        return character; // for instance for 32 (space)

    final int tailIndex = Math.round((characterValue - hangulUnicodeStartValue) % 28) - 1;
    final int vowelIndex = Math.round(((characterValue - hangulUnicodeStartValue - tailIndex) % 588) / 28);
    final int initialIndex = (characterValue - hangulUnicodeStartValue) / 588;
    final String leadString = initials.substring(initialIndex, initialIndex + 1);
    final String vowelString = vowels.substring(vowelIndex, vowelIndex + 1);
    final String tailString = tailIndex == -1 ? "" : finals.substring(tailIndex, tailIndex + 1);// may be -1 when there is no tail character
    return leadString + vowelString + tailString;
}
```

Note that `ㅎ` (from the initials) is not the same as `ᇂ` (from tails) as is for all initials vs tails.

Note also that, due to index starting at 0 instead of 1 as the example from The Korean Writing System, we have to subtract 1 from `tail` and not add 1 for `vowel` and `lead`

To test the above code, you can use, for instance, which contains two three and four character values:

```
@Test
public void deconstructKoreanCharacters() {
    final String koreanText = "항성은 항상 혼자 있는 것이 아니라, 두 개 이상의";
    for (int i = 0; i < koreanText.length(); i++) {
        final String character = koreanText.substring(i, i + 1);
        final String decomposedCharacters = getCharacter(character);
        System.out.println(character + ":" + decomposedCharacters);
    }
    Statics.doNothing();
}
```

If you need both characters from `ᆪ`, thus `ㄱ` and `ㅅ` this might be a bit manual work, as the number of possible tail characters is 27 (including single character tails)

Comment: @mwo07 I'm also quite happy with your question - for it had been bothering me for a while. (side note: interesting that when people don't understand a question, they assume the questioner is wrong.)